# How to do integration test in cloud foundry?

Tags: integration-testing, cloud-foundry, jacoco

I'm doing integration test in cloud foundry and I want to generate code coverage report. I found the jacoco agent in cloud foundry https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-jacoco_agent.md. But it only supports tcpclient mode. So is there any way to provide a tcpserver mode agent? Or is there any way I can do to do the integration test in cloud foundry?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but I do not believe the Java buildpack link you referenced is intended to be a server. It looks like the intent is to configure the agent to talk back to a server that you host elsewhere. It's probably easier that way. You don't have to worry about managing state in your server. Plus if you were to try and run in server mode, it looks like you'd need to assign a TCP route to your app, which may or may not be available (it depends on how your operator has configured CF).

Comment: @Daniel thanks for your valuable suggestions, maybe I should create a server for jacoco and then use tcpclient agent to transfer data.